# my model (sink) is rendering deformed, its fine in other views

Tags: cycles-render-engine

it was fine yesterday and i can't figure out what ive done

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3f6QZE_rYek0mwWIpD-GCzjDYRKPIoo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your displacement values on this material are extreme, decrease them to something low like 0.01.[image]

Comment: cheers Yousuf! its always something so obvious.